# Android Socket Connection loss?

Tags: java, android, sockets, client

I´m playing around with Sockets and wrote a test app to send text messages to a server running on my PC and have the server display them. I wrote a similar client in Java to test it and it worked. But now in Android, it seems to establish a connection to the server, but it only recieves the first message and subsequent messages won´t show up.
I thought, maybe the thread is only executing once, but that´s not the case since logcat recognizes the button presses.

### Android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText enter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final String fromUser = null;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        PrintWriter out = null;
                        BufferedReader in = null;
                        Socket clientSocket = null;
                        try {
                            clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.178.41", 5959);
                            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.d("---","cant make a connection");
                        }
                        String fromUser = enter.getText().toString();
                        if (fromUser != null) {
                            System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
                            out.println(fromUser);
                        }
                    }

                }).start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Server

```
public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting server!");
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try{
             ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5959);
             Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
             out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
             in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
             System.out.println("Established a connection with a user!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String inputLine;
        String outputLine = "Hey Client from Server!";

        out.println(outputLine);

        try {
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(inputLine);
            System.out.println("Client: " + inputLine);
            if (inputLine.equals("quit"))
                break;
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   

}
```

I cant figure out what is causing the problem, but its for sure a silly mistake...

Comment: Try to make the connection only once and make a reference of the socket and reuse it.Even better create a service which reconnects after every disconnect

Comment: Hey, how would you reuse the socket? Because after closing it, I have to create a new one

Comment: don't close it if you are going to receive messages continuously

Comment: ok, but if I try to connect to it from another socket, don´t I recieve an exception because the socket is already in use? or do I just close the socket connecting to the server socket and then I will be fine?

Comment: Try using socket-io library.it will maintain the connections for you.

Comment: No, you won't get a exception because the socket is already in use. You seem to be just guessing. Web servers handle thousands of connections at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your client is creating one connection and sending only one message per click.
2. Your server is only accepting one connection.
3. Your client is never closing the socket. Instead it is leaking it.
4. Your server is therefore never getting out of its read loop.
5. Even if it did, it would never accept a new client because of (2).
6. It will never received more than one message inside the loop because of (1).

In short your code makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Hey, so I have a solution, that is to let the server create the sockets in a while loop and close them a the end. But thats quite redundant and not performant. Is there a way to just use one socket?

Comment: That is neither redundant nor 'non-performant'. It is how TCP servers are written. But you could economize at the client end by using one connection for everything, instead of one per message, as I hinted in (1).